# There is a function which is both linear and multi linear which her input in not the zero matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

It's supposed to be simple but I'm struggling with that.

Let A, B ∈ Mn(F). Prove or disprove:
If a function T: Mn(F) → F is linear and multi-linear, then it is the zero function.

First, it looks like proof. I'm trying to use the definition of multi-linear which is using one matrix, two scalars, and two general rows, while to show linearity you must use two metrics with two scalars, (for example in a linear map) so I don't know how to continue (of course the obvious answer will be to use two metrics and to show the definition of the multi-linear, but I don't how, and I'm sure it is true)

Comment: "metric" and "matrix" are two entirely different things. A matrix $A$ is can be considered to be $n$ column vectors: $A = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf a_1&\mathbf a_2&\dots&\mathbf a_n\end{bmatrix}$. Multilinearity is for all $k. \bf v$ and for all $\alpha, \beta \in F$, we have $$T\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf a_1&\dots&\alpha \mathbf a_k + \beta\mathbf v&\dots&\mathbf a_n\end{bmatrix} = \alpha TA + \beta T\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf a_1&\dots&\mathbf v&\dots&\mathbf a_n\end{bmatrix}$$while linearity is for all $A, B \in M^n(F), T(\alpha A + \beta B) = \alpha TA + \beta TB$.

Comment: Now suppose $B = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1-\alpha}\beta\mathbf a_1&\dots&\mathbf v&\dots&\frac{1-\alpha}\beta\mathbf a_n\end{bmatrix}$.